# What is Sparql Query to get Company and its subidiary through dbpedia triple store

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia, triplestore

I am new to RDF

I am trying to get companies and number of its subsidaries through dbpedia

I started with writing below queries in sparql at http://dbpedia.org/sparql or [DBpedia SPARQL Explorer](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/)

```
select ?p ?v where {<http://dbpedia.org:8890/ontology/subsidiary ?p ?v}
```

And This:

```
 SELECT * WHERE {
  ?P <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/subsidiary> ?C 
}
```

See here

http://dbpedia.org:8890/ontology/subsidiary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should aggregate the results with `group by` and use count, e.g like:

```
SELECT str(?lab) as ?label ?com count(?subs) as ?count WHERE {
  ?com <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/subsidiary> ?subs .
  ?com rdfs:label ?lab .
filter langMatches(lang(?lab), 'en') .
} 
group by ?com ?lab
```

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20str%28?lab%29%20as%20?label%20?com%20count%28?subs%29%20as%20?count%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?com%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/subsidiary%3E%20?subs%20.%0D%0A%20%20?com%20rdfs%3alabel%20?lab%20.%0D%0Afilter%20langMatches%28lang%28?lab%29,%20%27en%27%29%20.%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?com%20?lab%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: Thanks, that is all i needed. Btw, can you please modify the query so that results show in descending order of subsidiaries i.e. the company with highest subsidiary shows first.

Comment: @Watt, just add `order by DESC(?count)`